# 20.04 LTS and B550 motherboard - ethernet problem

Tags: drivers, ethernet

First question so apologies for the long one. This is somewhat similar to other posts like this one: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/realtek-rtl8125-2-5gbe-ethernet-not-working-on-amd-b550-mobo/22469

However, I have scoured the internet and not found a usable solution yet. In the images attached you'll see:

1. I tried to install the driver from Realtek, however, the system indicates that `make` is not installed.
2. Alright, so to do that, I need `sudo apt-get build-essential`. However, since there's no internet connection, it doesn't know what to do. I tried installing build-essential using the tar file found here https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/build-essential, but it indicates that *dpkg-dev must be installed to build this package*.
3. Tried installing *dpkg-dev* from the tar file, but apparently there was no acceptable C compiler on the path.

This is installed on a system that has windows on a separate drive - that install of Windows needed the ethernet driver to be manually installed, but I cannot figure out how to install the Realtek driver on the linux system. I've also tried tethering my iphone to Linux, but apparently that has stopped working with iOS 14.

Thanks in advance! Pictures are in the links below:

Ethernet install error :
[image]

Build-essential error:

[image]

Additional error from `dpkg` :

[image]

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running, that does not have a make or c compiler in the standard path?

Comment: @ubfan1 good question - I followed the instructions listed here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview and here https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview. So part of that was simply downloading the ISO file here: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

This is 20.04.2.0. Do you think there's some kind of install problem?

Comment: You should be able to download the actual package instead of its source, and avoid solving build problems.  The "which make" command locates the make in your defined $PATH.  If the output is not /usr/bin/make, check your PATH (echo $PATH) to see that it includes /usr/bin. A USB connected wifi adapter may solve your problem too.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the reply. so ```which make``` doesn't return anything. However, something like ```which mimetype``` returns ```usr/bin/mimetype``` and I can view the usr folder. $PATH does however include usr/bin. There just appears to be nothing called ```make``` at all. Agree on the USB wifi or ethernet adapter, I will try that as well. As a side note, where would I go to download the whole package I need? I'm somewhat of a linux noob so I'm not sure how I would accomplish that.

Comment: Try https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/devel/make for the make package. I see make was installed automatically on my system, maybe pulled in from another package.

Comment: Final update for anyone reading this: could not get 20.04 LTS to work, and as a last-ditch effort tried 21.04 and it worked!! Clean install, no fiddling with drivers whatsoever, and the ethernet worked out of the box. Thanks for the help @ubfan1

Comment: You may write your own answer and accept it after a few days so it gets marked solved and may help others, and you get some points.

Answer (score 1):

Final update for anyone reading this: could not get 20.04 LTS to work, and as a last-ditch effort tried 21.04 and it worked!! Clean install, no fiddling with drivers whatsoever, and the ethernet worked out of the box.